# How can I efficiently iterate through a pandas dataset that has millions of rows and pass a function to every row?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, bigdata, python-multithreading

I have a pandas dataframe with 7 million instances of flight data. the flight data comes with the location and the time which I am using to pull weather for that time. Right now for 1000 instances, my code is taking 83 seconds. This is way too long considering I got 7 million to go through. I am not sure how to go about this. I've read that *itertuples* would be a bit quicker or maybe using *Dask* or *multitreading*.

```
import warnings
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from meteostat import Point, Daily
import airportsdata
import time
import threading
import os

warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)

airports = airportsdata.load('IATA')
all1 = pd.DataFrame()
all2 = pd.DataFrame()

first_mil = pd.read_csv('first_mil.csv')

def weather_from_IATA(airport, time):
    """
    uses airport data from "airportsdata" to find latitude and longitude 
    and pass lat and lon into meteostat, which will return the weather at
    that airport at that time.
    """
    lon, lat = airports[airport]['lat'], airports[airport]['lon']

    # Set time period
    start, end = time, time

    # Create Point for airport
    location = Point(lon, lat)

    # Get daily data for location
    data = Daily(location, start, end)
    weather_time = data.fetch()

    # =================================================================
    return weather_time

for air in range(1000):
    Iata = (first_mil.iloc[air]['ORIGIN'])
    flight_time = (first_mil.iloc[air]['FL_DATE'])
    weather_data = weather_from_IATA(Iata, flight_time)
    all1 = all1.append(weather_data)

end1 = time.time()
print("iteration for append took: ", (end1 - start), "sec")
```

Comment: `first_mil.apply(lambda row: weather_from_IATA(row["ORIGIN"],row["FL_DATE"]), axis=1)`

Comment: `all1 = list(map(weather_from_IATA, *map(first_mil.get, ['ORIGIN', 'FL_DATE'])))`  This is essentially the same as an `itertuples` type of answer.  Less confusing would be `all1 = list(map(weather_from_IATA, first_mil['ORIGIN'], first_mil['FL_DATE']))`

Comment: @piRSquared I just ran what you said and it cut the time from 84 sec to 28sec. This is great but im still struggling with time. 28sec for 1000 instances is still 54hours for 7 million rows

Comment: I understand.  You need a more vectorized solution.  That requires rewriting your function.  I gave you probably the quickest way to iterate through each row via Python, but it's not enough.  If I have time, I'll pick apart your function to understand what it's doing.

Comment: Where to download the `first_mil.csv`?

Comment: using `%prun`, you can look for potential bottleneck on your implementation

Comment: @Corralien https://mega.nz/file/fgUUzJgI#DFd2ovuYhL10zwvTcoFZDKWedKAvj_lFcguaZqNbSQM